# Drush installed in local directory but command not found?

Tags: drush

I know that Drush is a huge time saver so I'm trying to get familiar with it but I keep getting

> command not found

error after installation. I've required and removed Drush a couple of times just to make sure I'm doing this correctly.

Here's what I did:

```
$ cd mydrupal
$ composer require drush/drush
```

After I run the above command many things install:

> Using version ^9.3 for drush/drush
>
> ./composer.json has been updated
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Package operations: 57 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Installing... (many things download and install (100%))

And I end up with this:

> Writing lock file
>
> Generating autoload files
>
> > Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> >     Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess

Then I get my command line prompt and I run

```
$ drush status
```

and I get this:

> -bash: drush: command not found

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a global command. Which is not installed or symlinked into one of your Mac's autoloaded `bin` directories (or is not added to your global `$PATH`).

Simplest option you have now is to use the local command:

```
$ cd mydrupal
$ vendor/drush/drush/drush status
```

Alternatively you may want to install [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) on your Mac (to be used together with the [Composer template for Drupal projects](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)). Which when you are inside a project that has a local Drush installed automatically associates the global `drush` command to the project's local Drush.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was due to config_sync_directory not being defined in settings.php.  Example...

```
  $settings['config_sync_directory'] = 'sites/default/files';
```